# MVC Getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden second time opening view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-express

I have started to get an unusual error starting this week when requesting one specific view in my project. I have a cshtml file (partial view and controller function only contains a single line for returning the view) and it used to work fine but now if I access it twice I get an 403.14 error code, restarting the computer doesnt help. None of the other files in the same controller / folder have any problem.

Yesterday I tried to rename the view multiple times and after renaming it worked once but if I refreshed the page I got the error again.

I asked a friend to download the source code and see if he had the same problem and he could open it up multiple times.

Have anyone else had this problem?

The version of MVC is: 5.2.3

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult CreateCaseModal()
   {
      return PartialView();
   }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Create case</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group" ng-if="modalVM.showOrganizations">
        <label>Organization</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Organization 1</option>
            <option>Organization 2</option>
            <option>Organization 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"  ng-if="modalVM.showTypeOfInjuries">
        <label>Type of injury</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Org 1</option>
            <option>Org 2</option>
            <option>Org 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Case number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modalVM.create()">Create</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="modalVM.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Asp.Net MVC are you using? Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I thought this was the solution but today I was testing again and after I made some changes to the view, it started with the same error again. I tried to restart visual studio, IIS express and the computer but nothing worked. Also another view also stopped working, the page is also a modal and looks almost like the one provided.

Comment: @user1842278, did you figure out what your problem was? I'm having the same strange issue.